# Excel 2007: How to extract all possible 2 pair combination out of a list and displaying them in 2 seperate columns

Tags: list, combinations, excel-2007

I got the following problem: I have x, y and z values to describe the location of a number of objects. Each value is written in its individual cell.

[These are my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zKXm.png)

```
ID     X, Center of (object)    Y, Center of (object)   Z, Center of (object)
206    497.216                  1221.0065               142.086
210    397.8002                 1226.8419               142.0019
213    432.8625                 1227.1501               223.5755
216    413.0157                 1244.3332               138.5435
217    461.5609                 1108.214                78.106
218    464.9693                 1250.1958               140.4711
```

What I want to do is to calculate the distance between 2 objects for all possible combinations. I normally do that by creating the combinations all by hand, so that my data in the end look like that:

[This is how the newly arranged data should look like, with all combinations but no duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV6qc.png)

Is there any way to do that automatically? Getting all combinations of objects out of one list next to each other, while each value stays in his own cell so I can still do my calculations?
Any help is really appreciated! I am really going crazy doing the arrangements by hand... :/

```
ID1   X         Y           Z           ID2    X            Y           Z
206   497.216   1221.0065   142.086     210    397.8002 1226.8419   142.0019
206   497.216   1221.0065   142.086     213    432.8625 1227.1501   223.5755
```

For all items (IDs) in my list of data, I want to be able to calculate the distance of that ID with another ID.

For instance, for `ID 206`, I want to create combinations (calculations) so that ID `210, 213, 216, 217` are calculated, then for `ID 210` etc the same.

Comment: So you want to calculate 206 with 210, 213, 216 etc? Also 210 with 213, 216 etc?  Formulas alone won't be able to do it easily, VBA or some programming language will be able to

Comment: Basically yes. I mean the formula to calculate the distance is not the problem. The problem for me is to arrange the data as shown in figure 2 so i can easily apply the formula in excel without creating every combination by copy/paste. Unforunately I am not a programmer but biologist, so I came here to ask for help...

Comment: Your question needs to be improved, I will partially try to improve it a little bit, but the community has locked it for that reason.  Whoever assists you will most likely do it in a programming language/VBA (I would just do it in VBA for Excel since that is the backend language, and already integrated with Excel).  It will take a few hours' testing for whoever does that, as this community usually assist people with 'code solutions that needs assistance', people will only assist if the solutions are small.  Although not impossible/hard to do its also not simple either.